# Finish typing event without submit

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to create an editText that autocomplete the text that the user types. For example only after the user types something (like **Lon**) the app can suggest London, so insert **don** after **Lon**. I alreay have the service that give me the advices but I don't know what kind of event use for call this service only after the user writes something (i don't want call the service after every letter).

I tried this, but it works only after that the user press submit, but i want to catch the event "The user is no longer typing"

```
 bornCityTxt.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            //mycode
            return true;
        }
    });
```

And less important, how can I have at the same time the user text and the hint in one edit text?

Really thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a listener and then check in afterTextChanged how many letters have been entered

```
Handler h = new Handler();
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(s.toString().length()>0){
                h.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null); // Cancels previous call
                h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                      @Override
                      public void run()
                      {
                         //do something with entered text
                      }
                 }, 1000); // 1 second 
            }
            else{


            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I try this solution, but for some reason despite the event is throw after the text changes, the letters that I type is show in the edittext after the method is solved, so after the call to the server. For this delay seems that I'm not typing

Comment: I don't know what exactly happens in your app, but what if you call your service after delay. Edited code

Answer (score 0):

Try an OnKeyListener:

```
bornCityTxt.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            //your code
            return true;
        }
});
```

Hope this helps!